# How can I forward a gpg key via ssh-agent?

Tags: ssh, gnupg, ssh-agent

I can use the ssh configuration file to enable the forwarding of ssh keys added to ssh-agent. How can I do the same with gpg keys?

Comment: Both answers suggest running socat to expose the GPG agent unix socket on a tcp port. However, unlike unix sockets, TCP ports do not have the same level on access control. In particular, _every_ user on the same host can now connect to your GPG agent. This is probably ok if you have a single-user laptop, but if any other users can also log into the same system (the system where the GPG agent is running), they can also access your GPG agent, posing a significant security problem. Letting socat directly start SSH using the EXEC address type is probably the best way to fix this.

Comment: For another presentation of the openssh 6.7+ solution, see https://2015.rmll.info/IMG/pdf/an-advanced-introduction-to-gnupg.pdf

Comment: [This](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/gnupg/users/77816) was useful to me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

EDIT: This answer is obsolete now that proper support has been implemented in OpenSSH, see Brian Minton's answer.

SSH is only capable of forwarding tcp connections within the tunnel.

You can, however, use a program like `socat` to relay the unix socket over TCP, with something like that (you will need socat both on the client and the server hosts):

```
# Get the path of gpg-agent socket:
GPG_SOCK=$(echo "$GPG_AGENT_INFO" | cut -d: -f1)

# Forward some local tcp socket to the agent
(while true; do
    socat TCP-LISTEN:12345,bind=127.0.0.1 UNIX-CONNECT:$GPG_SOCK;
done) &

# Connect to the remote host via ssh, forwarding the TCP port
ssh -R12345:localhost:12345 host.example.com

# (On the remote host)
(while true; do
    socat UNIX-LISTEN:$HOME/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent,unlink-close,unlink-early TCP4:localhost:12345;
done) &
```

Test if it works out with `gpg-connect-agent`. Make sure that GPG_AGENT_INFO is undefined on the remote host, so that it falls back to the `$HOME/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent` socket.

Now hopefully all you need is a way to run all this automatically!

Comment: Well the ssh agent keys are forwarded automatically when the forwarding is set in the configuration file. I will try this out.

Comment: You're right, ssh-agent uses a unix socket too, but has special support for it (little bit tired here :) Nevertheless, the solution should still work.

Comment: For this solution, my gpg-agent would be publicy accessible via port 12345 if I was not behind a firewall/NAT. This should be mentioned in the answer please.

Comment: I'm guessing your last edit fixed that issue, Jonas? it's only binding to `localhost` now.

Comment: This fails for me with the following argument from the remote host's `gpg-connect-agent`:
    `can't connect to server: ec=31.16383
    gpg-connect-agent: error sending RESET command: Invalid value passed to IPC`. The remote `socat` then dies. The local `socat` dies and utters `socat[24692] E connect(3, AF=1 "", 2): Invalid argument`. [This page](http://snafu.priv.at/interests/crypto/remotegpg.html) leads me to believe that this will never work, because the agent doesn't store the key (just the passphrase). Has this been confirmed to work by anyone?

Comment: @jmtd yes, this fixes the privacy issue. However, I was unable to get it to work with socat, which is why I hacked up a python script which does the trick: http://fpaste.org/Um0D/ (this may need improvement). Other issues I had with socat was lingering tcp sockets and stuff.

Comment: @JonasWielicki - the fpaste.org link is now broken. Can you provide your script via a new pfaste.org link or better yet as an A to this Q?

Comment: @slm I used fpaste as it was an informational comment. In fact, I cannot even recall what it was, although the comments make be believe that it was a simple socat-like utility binding to localhost and forwarding the traffic between the tcp and the unix socket.

Answer (score 25):

OpenSSH's new Unix Domain Socket Forwarding can do this directly starting with version 6.7.

You should be able to something like:

```
ssh -R /home/bminton/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:/home/bminton/.gnupg/S-gpg-agent -o "StreamLocalBindUnlink=yes" -l bminton 192.168.1.9
```

Comment: @DrewR. Glad to hear that.

Comment: I found a required critical detail: on the remote (private key-less) machine, the _public_ key of the signing identity must be present.  Local gpg version 2.1.15 OS X, remote 2.1.11 linux.

Comment: If you have your pyblic keys published on the keyservers, you can setup the remote keyring with something like `gpg -K --keyid-format long | grep '\[SC\]' | grep -v expired | sed 's#sec \+[^/]\+/\([0-9A-F]\+\).*#\1#' | ssh user@target 'xargs -n 1 gpg --recv-key'`.


We can figure out the socket names automatically: `ssh -A user@target -R "$(ssh user@target 'gpgconf --list-dirs agent-socket')":"$(gpgconf --list-dirs agent-extra-socket)" 'gpg -K'`

Comment: This does not work with OpenSSH 8.1 client (mac) and OpenSSH server 7.6 (ubuntu), even after exporting and importing the public key. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but `passwordstore` decryption fails with `gpg: decryption failed: No secret key`.

Is it intentional that the remote gpg agent file has the dot replaced by a hyphen?

Comment: It seems that on Ubuntu 18.04, systemd owns the file with the host's extra socket, and the ssh deamon cannot bind to it (joutnalctl tells me address already in use and ` error: unix_listener: cannot bind to path: /run/user/1001/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra`). Is this answer still current?

Answer (score 14):

In new versions of GnuPG or Linux distributions the paths of the sockets can change. These can be found out via

```
$ gpgconf --list-dirs agent-extra-socket
```

and

```
$ gpgconf --list-dirs agent-socket
```

Then add these paths to your SSH configuration:

```
Host remote
  RemoteForward <remote socket> <local socket>
```

Quick solution for copying the public keys:

```
scp .gnupg/pubring.kbx remote:~/.gnupg/
```

On the remote machine, activate GPG agent:

```
echo use-agent >> ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf
```

On the remote machine, also modify the SSH server configuration and add this parameter (/etc/ssh/sshd_config):

```
StreamLocalBindUnlink yes
```

Restart SSH server, reconnect to the remote machine - then it should work.

Comment: A more detailed tutorial including some troubleshooting can be found here: https://mlohr.com/gpg-agent-forwarding/

Comment: In case the remote host runs a current version of Debian, it seems running `systemctl --global mask --now gpg-agent.service gpg-agent.socket gpg-agent-ssh.socket gpg-agent-extra.socket gpg-agent-browser.socket` is required to prevent systemd from launching a socket stealing remote gpg-agent. According to https://bugs.debian.org/850982 this is the intended behavior.

Comment: You might need to prevent the remote `gpg-agent` from starting and removing the forwarded socket. This is also described in the gpg wiki. What they don't say is how to do that. `echo no-autostart >> ~/.ssh/gpg-agent.conf` on the remote machine worked for me.

Comment: Test whether it works with `echo test | gpg --clearsign`

Comment: `use-agent` is no longer necessary, nowadays it is a dummy option https://gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Configuration-Options.html#index-use_002dagent

Comment: When trying to forward the local gpg-agent's `extra` socket to the remote host, I always get `error fetching identities: invalid format` when checking `ssh-add -L` on the remote machine after connecting. I had to forward the actual `S.gpg-agent.ssh` socket from the local to the remote and after doing that, everything works great.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do the same, and based my script on the solution by b0fh, with a few tiny modifications: It traps exits and kills background processes, and it uses the "fork" and "reuseaddr" options to socat, which saves you the loop (and makes the background socat cleanly kill-able).

The whole thing sets up all forwards in one go, so it probably comes closer to an automated setup.

Note that on the remote host, you will need:

1. The keyrings you intend to use to sign/en/decrypt stuff.
2. Depending on the version of gpg on the remote, a fake `GPG_AGENT_INFO` variable. I prefill mine with `~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:1:1` - the first 1 is a PID for the gpg agent (I fake it as "init"'s, which is always running), the second is the agent protocol version number. This should match the one running on your local machine.

```
#!/bin/bash -e

FORWARD_PORT=${1:-12345}

trap '[ -z "$LOCAL_SOCAT" ] || kill -TERM $LOCAL_SOCAT' EXIT

GPG_SOCK=$(echo "$GPG_AGENT_INFO" | cut -d: -f1)
if [ -z "$GPG_SOCK" ] ; then
    echo "No GPG agent configured - this won't work out." >&2
    exit 1
fi

socat TCP-LISTEN:$FORWARD_PORT,bind=127.0.0.1,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CONNECT:$GPG_SOCK &
LOCAL_SOCAT=$!

ssh -R $FORWARD_PORT:127.0.0.1:$FORWARD_PORT socat 'UNIX-LISTEN:$HOME/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent,unlink-close,unlink-early,fork,reuseaddr TCP4:localhost:$FORWARD_PORT'
```

I believe there's also a solution that involves just one SSH command invocation (connecting back from the remote host to the local one) using `-o LocalCommand`, but I couldn't quite figure out how to conveniently kill that upon exit.

Comment: Aren't you missing some 'user@host' argument before socat, in the last command? Anyhow even after fixing that, this fails for me with "socat[6788] E connect(3, AF=2 127.0.0.1:0, 16): Connection refused" popping up locally, when trying gpg-connect-agent remotely.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to modifying `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` with `StreamLocalBindUnlink yes`, you can instead prevent the creation of the socket files that need replacing:

```
systemctl --global mask --now \
  gpg-agent.service \
  gpg-agent.socket \
  gpg-agent-ssh.socket \
  gpg-agent-extra.socket \
  gpg-agent-browser.socket
```

Note that this affects **all** users on the host.

Bonus: How to test GPG agent forwarding is working:

- Local: `ssh -v -o RemoteForward=${remote_sock}:${local_sock} ${REMOTE}`
- Check that `${remote_sock}` is shown in the verbose output from ssh
- Remote: `ls -l ${remote_sock}`
- Remote: `gpg --list-secret-keys`

  - You should see lots of `debug1` messages from ssh showing the forwarded traffic

If that doesn't work (as it didn't for me) you can trace which socket GPG is accessing:

```
strace -econnect gpg --list-secret-keys
```

Sample output:

```
connect(5, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/run/user/14781/gnupg/S.gpg-agent"}, 35) = 0
```

In my case the path being accessed perfectly matched `${remote_sock}`, *but* that socket was not created by `sshd` when I logged in, despite adding `StreamLocalBindUnlink yes` to my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. I was created by systemd upon login.

(Note I was too cowardly to *restart* sshd, since I've no physical access to the host right now. `service reload sshd` clearly wasn't sufficient...)

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

According to [GnuPG Wiki](https://wiki.gnupg.org/AgentForwarding), you have to forward the remote socket `S.gpg-agent.extra` to local socket `S.gpg-agent`.
Furthermore you need to enable `StreamLocalBindUnlink` on the server.
Keep in mind that you also need the public part of your key available on remote *GnuPG*.

Use `gpgconf --list-dir agent-socket` respectively `gpgconf --list-dir agent-extra-socket` on the remote to get the actual paths.

---

### Summary

1. Addded configuration on remote `/etc/sshd_config`:

   ```
   StreamLocalBindUnlink yes
   ```
2. Import your public key on remote:

   ```
   gpg --export <your-key> >/tmp/public
   scp /tmp/public <remote-host>:/tmp/public
   ssh <remote-host> gpg --import /tmp/public
   ```
3. Command to connect through SSH with gpg-agent forwarding enabled: (paths for my Debian)

   ```
   ssh -R /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra <remote-host>
   ```

Comment: @brian minton: It does not work for me if not forwarding to the extra socket.